# Excel, if Excel cell is X, Y or Z then display 1, 2 or 3

Tags: excel-formula

I need help with code for excel.

What I need is if a cell contains "Achieved" then display 1, "Partially Achieved" display 2 and if "Not Achieved" display 3.

Can someone help with what I need to enter?

Thanks

Comment: IF function will work for you

Comment: Thanks @dbmitch but what would the formula look like, I have tried a few options, but get errors or no response

Comment: Post what you have tried. Edit your question to do that. Don't post that in a comment.

Comment: A simple switch would do the trick as well
=SWITCH(A1,"Achieved",1,"Partially Achieved",2,"Not Achieved",3)
Where A1 is the cell you want to check of course

Comment: @Zephire write this up as it definitely belongs up there with the other two answers, 'cos it will get +1 from me... Oh and let me know!

Comment: Done as requested! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=IF(A1="Achieved",1,IF(A1="Partially Achieved",2,IF(A1="Not Achieved",3,"NA")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
=iferror(match(A1, {"Achieved", "Partially Achieved", "Not Achieved"}, 0), "")
```

fwiw, to perform the reverse (with 1, 2 or 3 in a cell) use,

```
=iferror(choose(A1, "Achieved", "Partially Achieved", "Not Achieved"), "")
```

Comment: This is much neater than having lots of nested if statements.

Comment: Thank you @SolarMike. It was purposed to provide an avenue for future users (beyond referencing a lookup table when the choices become unmanageable).

Answer (score 2):

```
=SWITCH(A1,"Achieved",1,"Partially Achieved",2,"Not Achieved",3)
```

Where A1 is the cell you want to check of course.

Answer (score 0):

For those without SWITCH (and half the length):

```
=MATCH(LEFT(A1),{"A","P","N"},0)
```