# Generate words based on cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here][1]I haven't used Excel since high school (2004-2005) but I was pretty proficient in writing formulas back then based on static and dynamic cell values. I'm currently trying to make a spreadsheet that can keep up with statistical data based on yes and no inputs (or 1 and 0 if you prefer binary).

In a game, I am managing a business and want to be able to keep track of employees based on their success. Success is a yes/no value. I'd like to have a table on sheet 2 that has the entire success/failure history of the player and on sheet 1 have a brief overview of their history that's listed on sheet 2 (overall success rate, success rate of last 10 inputs, and success rate of last 5 inputs).

I may or may not be able to figure out the formulas for those. If not, I'll be sure to research before asking for help on that. What I can't figure out is how to assign a word value for a given success rate. For example, I'd like J7 to give a value of "Trusted", "Dependable", "Endorsed", or "Warning" based on the value in K7. If the value of K7 is 90%-100% J7 should populated "Trusted". If the value of K7 is 80%-89% J7 should populate "Dependable". If the value of K7 is 70%-79% J7 should populate "Endorsed". If lower than 70% J7 should populate "Warning".

I'm trying to make the spreadsheet easy to use so that when I expand in the game I am able to share the spreadsheet with new branch owners to keep track of players working under them. That's why I would like the spreadsheet to be easy to manage so it doesn't take them long to figure it out and it doesn't take a long time to manage the spreadsheet so it doesn't rob them of game time.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check out the answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50661103/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike I've tried using that formula but cannot get it to work for a range of values.

Comment: If the question has been answered, then please proceed per [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and ask a new question. Do not revise your question in a manner that obfuscates legitimate responses to the original inquiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in K7,

```
=LOOKUP(J7, {0,0.7,0.8,0.9}, {"Warning","Endorsed","Dependable","Trusted"})
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error message,
"You may not use reference operations (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Conditional Formatting criteria."

Comment: I suppose your pcts are not numbers but text that look like numbers but the formula is sound. See attached image.

Comment: If you have text that look like numbers, don't try to 'bandaid' a formula solution; fix the data instead.

Comment: Hey! It worked! I was trying to use the conditional formatting option under the Home tab rather than writing the formula in directly. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the lookup function as noted by Jeeped or simply using the IF function. Try using the following in you J column next to the first row of data and populate all the way to where the row where your data in K column goes:

```
= IF(K1<0.7, "Warning", IF( 
     AND(K1>=0.7, K1<0.8), "Endorsed", IF(
         AND(K1>=0.8, K1<0.9), "Dependable", "Trusted")))
```

Comment: I just saw  it. Thanks, I modified it. I'm new to this environment and hopefully will get a hang of it soon.